# Deserealizing JSON object using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have API endpoint, that returning my JSON Object

Here is it

```
 {
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 182,
            "title": "1-Day Private Beijing Tour to Tian'anmen Square, Forbidden City and Badaling Great Wall",
            "price": "162",
            "duration": "8",
            "duration_type": "1",
            "cover_image": {
                "id": 308,
                "img_path": "upload/images",
                "img_file": "6d637884086151b30fe12db52fbaf5eb.jpg",
                "status": "",
                "created_at": "2018-02-27 02:25:36",
                "updated_at": "2018-02-27 02:25:36",
                "destination_id": "182",
                "is_cover": "0",
                "url": "https://api.xplorpal.com/upload/images/300x300/6d637884086151b30fe12db52fbaf5eb.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 183,
            "title": "One Day Private Beijing Tour to Mutianyu Great Wall and Summer Palace ",
            "price": "197",
            "duration": "8",
            "duration_type": "1",
            "cover_image": {
                "id": 305,
                "img_path": "upload/images",
                "img_file": "1f8a09ddffb80ef9232f3511893ae5c4.jpg",
                "status": "",
                "created_at": "2018-02-27 02:22:19",
                "updated_at": "2018-03-01 23:01:55",
                "destination_id": "183",
                "is_cover": "0",
                "url": "https://api.xplorpal.com/upload/images/300x300/1f8a09ddffb80ef9232f3511893ae5c4.jpg"
            }
        }
 ]
}
```

I need to deserialize it

So I wrote this model

```
    public class CoverImage
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string img_path { get; set; }
    public string img_file { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string destination_id { get; set; }
    public string is_cover { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public string duration_type { get; set; }
    public CoverImage cover_image { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

And trying to this like this

```
var responseExperiences = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RootObject>>(content);
```

But when I run the project, I have this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TravelApp.Models.GettingExperiences+Results]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your JSON shows one object `result` corresponding to `RootObject`.

But you are trying to deserialize an **array** (`IEnumerable<>`) of `RootObject`

You should use this to deserialiaze the JSON showed :

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

Comment: Yeah, it fixed issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your API returns an object with a single property named `result`, not a collection. You should deserialize into a `RootObject` object.

Answer (score 1):

Your api return single object named **result** not a collection you simply need to desearilize as a single object like.

```
var responseExperiences = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```